# Acumatica: Why Some User Becomes Duplicate When Modified?

Tags: acumatica

I added new users with roles designated to it and got no error. But when I add role or reset password or update info and then try to save I got error of duplicate Primary_Key.

**Primary Key Error** 
[image: https://imgur.com/a/yo4rsXi]

So I delete the user and add again with correct info then it saved but when I look into the user it listed with duplicate.

**Duplicate User** 
[image: https://imgur.com/a/yo4rsXi]

How can I fix it?

Comment: In which Acumatica version you have that behavior?

Comment: @Yuriy Zaletskyy Version 5.30.1672. It only occur after we added new company to restart new this January.